# Logs files suddenly stopped to be filled

Tags: 2010, logging, uls

I have just installed a setup a new SP 2010 server.

I don't know why, but suddenly, logs files stopped to be filled (and so ULS viewer remains empty).

At the time of the last log entry, I was setting up the UPSA, but I don't think it matters.

How can I check if my log settings are correct ? I just want the default logging behavior, so I can accept to reset something if required.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your farm account is a member of the local group "Performance Log Users"

Answer (score 4):

Can you restart the  SharePoint 2010 Tracing Service and the SharePoint 2010 Administration  Services  to see whether the logs are generating again. You can check the configuration in Central Administration [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656.aspx)

Comment: already tried, even rebooted. No success

Answer (score 3):

In my case (*SP 2013*) the ULS logs were not genereated and I had no entries in *Windows Event Log* as well, because the *SharePoint Tracing Service* (*SPTraceV4*) was accidentally stopped:

```
Tracing service is not running
Symptoms: No trace output is being recorded in the trace logs and no errors are being logged to the Windows log.
```

See source [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513058).

Answer (score 2):

In my case. I installed June 2013 CU about a week ago. Today I had a need to go to log and notice it has not been generating since the day I applied CU.

I went to each SharePoint server and noticed "SharePoint Tracing Service" logon changed to domain account. It should be "Local Service". I changed the login to Local Service and restarted "SharePoint 2010 Tracing" and boom it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the log folder (typically C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS) for newer files? A new log file is created every 30 minutes.

Have you checked logging settings on central administration via Monitoring / Configure diagnostic logging? Try to select 'All Categories' and then set 'Least critical event to report to the trace log' to 'Verbose' and make sure that the logging path is as expected.

I suppose you have already checked the disk space...

Answer (score 0):

Check disk space, if it's too low, it may stop overall. Also, check your timer job service, make sure it's running and no errors are being reported (check ULS logs). I've run into issues with logging with both of these items.

Comment: 'check in the logs why the logs are not generated'... there's somethnig weird in this sentence ;)

Comment: LOL good point.... need more coffee